# Why certain IPs redirect us to 0.0.0.0?

Tags: networking, ip, browser

I have seen many times when I try to connect to default gateways through my web browser , it redirects me to 0.0.0.0 . And it shows firefox can't found 0.0.0.0 . Why this happens? If the IP 0.0.0.0 have specific significance. Is it possible to have IP like 0.0.0.0? Can anybody explain me this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is the "any ip". It'll match anything basically. That's why in a routing table the default gateway is usually given as 0.0.0.0 ip.of.default.gateway

Comment: You probably have a hosts file that is redirecting certain domain names to 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one default gateway and you pass through default gateway to reach hosts that are not in your subnet.

when you set route for some default gateway, and print that route it will show that connections to 0.0.0.0 are made via IP of default gateway , meaning connecting anywhere
outside own subnet is made via that IP.

Other situation where you can use 0.0.0.0 is when you want to bind some service to listen
on all interfaces (multiple public private ips, multiple NICs)